# Kernel module for flushing cpu caches

Tags: caching, kernel-module, inline-assembly, cpu-cache

I have built a simple kernel module, which uses `wbinvd()` instruction (x86), in order to write-back and then invalidate all cache blocks. 
Which is the best way to check the functionality or the success of this instruction? 
I 've already tried to load the module while I'm repeatedly accessing an array, but no significant latency (in cycles) have been noticed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your module multi-code aware? Probably the best way to check this is by using *perf*. For example the event *CYCLE_ACTIVITY.CYCLES_L1D_MISS* (event num = a3, umask = 08) seems promising.

Comment: Yes, actually this privilledged assembly instruction flushes -at least- Last Level Cache and in some architectures flushes all private classes two. Just to be sure I also added `on_each_cpu()` and now the `wbinvd()` is executed in all CPUs. Thank you for the indication, I ll back when I ll try monitoring this with perf :)